# Does Selenium initiated WebBrowser consume the same brandwidth like the normal browser?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser, webdriver

If I visit 100 website in a normal browser, after that I visit the same websites with selenium web driver, it consumes the same brandwidth?

Comment: Did you mean *bandwidth*? selenium doesn't have its own browser, it uses the same browser you use as a regular user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Plus whatever bandwidth is consumed by communicating with the selenium server.

**Actually...**

Your regular browser might have extensions that add extra bandwidth. So maybe not.

Comment: what is actually the selenium server?

Answer (score 0):

As @Guy mentioned, *Selenium* doesn't have its own browser and it uses the same browser which you use as a regular user.

Now, there wouldn't be any substancial difference between the two processes of invoking the ***Browser Client*** **Manually** or through **Selenium**. Albeit ***Browsing Session*** initiated by *Selenium* will contain some additional (command-line) arguments e.g.

- `--allow-insecure-localhost`
- `--disable-background-networking`
- `--disable-client-side-phishing-detection`
- `--disable-default-apps`
- `--disable-extensions`
- `--disable-hang-monitor`
- `--disable-infobars`
- `--disable-popup-blocking`
- `--disable-prompt-on-repost`
- `--disable-sync`
- `--disable-web-resources`
- `--enable-automation`
- `--enable-logging`

Most importantly,

- **`--test-type=webdriver`**

Now, these information is exchanged between the *Server* and *Client* using either [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.0](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html) or [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) and from *Automation* perspective your work won't be effected.

### Conclusion

You can safely ignore the infrastructure (**bandwidth**) and protocol level functioning of the *Browser Client* and move ahead.